# How to update Roblox without the app store

Tags: roblox

I want to update Roblox without any app stores, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why? Do you not have the app store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, this is not allowed legally, due to the guidelines that both Apple and Android try to follow by:

> Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or
> write data outside the designated container area, **nor may they
> download, install, or execute code which introduces or changes
> features or functionality of the app**, including other apps.

I found this quote from [Apple’s App Development Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#before-you-submit), and Googles has nearly the same guidelines as well.

Comment: There is nothing legal about that

Comment: @RayWu What do you mean? Apple and Android both have this set guideline in place, meaning breaking it is technically a violation of their terms of service and thus is not allowed (or illegal). I didn’t mean illegal by government means.

Comment: Alright but that sounded like it was about the law lol sorry

Comment: Thank you guys!

Comment: @Essie You’re welcome! If it worked, remember to click the check mark so people know it does!

Answer (score -1):

I don’t believe so - however there are some videos online claiming you can play without updating. I won’t link any here because I don’t quite trust them. I suppose you could download it off of google play and technically wouldn’t have to update it via the App Store, but I don’t know if this would help in your scenario.

Comment: Google Play does not work on iOS